# Proof of rayleigh-jeans formula

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I'm trying to understand proof of [rayleigh-jeans formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law) from the book "Quantum Physics" by Resnick and Eisberg page 10 and i'm confused. I graduated in math but i'm a big fan of physics. I tried really hard and there are some questions.
for example i don't understand three relations $E(x,t)$, $E(y,t)$ and $E(Z,t)$  (under page 10) are exactly what physical quantities and defined on what domain.
i will be glad if i can a discussion about this proof maybe out of this site.

Answer (score 2):

The equations in question (which you can see on page 28 of [this link](https://umadosedeinteligencia.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/quantum-physics-2nd-eisbergresnick.pdf)) describe the amplitude of electromagnetic radiation in a cavity. $E$ is the field, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the orthogonal directions of the edges of this cubic cavity, and $t$ is the time dimension (these are standing waves in X, Y and Z).

Because the cavity is metallic, you know the boundary condition for the electric field (must be zero at the boundary). Thus the $\sin$ relationship requires an integer number of (half) wavelengths to fit in the box.

Since the box is cubic, $x, y, z$ etc are defined on $[0,~a]$, and $t>=0$

Answer (score 2):

The standing wave in the cavity is set up in one dimension $x$ and is of the form

$E(x,t)=E_0 \sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi x}{\lambda} \right)\sin 2\pi \nu t$

This is equation **1-6** on page **8** of the textbook and the justification for this assuming metallic walls is explained starting on page **6**.

Representing this wave as a "3-D" drawing is very difficult but the illustrator for the textbook has done a good job to show that the nodes which are points in one dimension become planes in three dimensions.

[image]

Going back to a simpler representation one could draw a standing wave as follows where there is no component of the electric field in the y-direction.

[image]

Using the ideas of superposition of waves this can be redrawn as follows:

[image]

where the standing wave is the sum of two component standing waves with $E^2=E^2_{\rm x} + E^2_{\rm z}$ and $\lambda^2 = \lambda^2_{\rm x} + \lambda^2_{\rm z} $.

---

The complexity of the situation and hence the difficulty in visualising the waves can be gauged by going back to what was called a one dimensional standing wave.

$E(x,t)=E_0 \sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi x}{\lambda} \right)\sin 2\pi \nu t$

This equation could equally well represent a two dimensional wave in the xy or xz plane where the nodal points in one dimension now become nodal lines perpendicular to the x-axis

[image]

and a three dimensional wave where the nodal points in one dimension become nodal planes orthogonal to the x-axis which is the textbook diagram but with the nodal planes being parallel to yz plane.

---

In the textbook derivation standing waves along directions which are orthogonal to the cube walls are forced to have a zero electric field at the boundaries which leads to a set of standing wave equations.

$E(x,t)=E_{0\rm x} \sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi x}{\lambda_{\rm x}} \right)\sin 2\pi \nu t$
$E(y,t)=E_{0\rm y} \sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi y}{\lambda_{\rm y}} \right)\sin 2\pi \nu t$
$E(z,t)=E_{0\rm z} \sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi z}{\lambda_{\rm z}} \right)\sin 2\pi \nu t$

These components are added together (the reverse of what I did above) to form a 3-D standing wave subject to $E^2=E^2_{\rm x} + E^2_{\rm y}+E^2_{\rm z}$ and $\lambda^2 = \lambda^2_{\rm x} + \lambda^2_{\rm y} + \lambda^2_{\rm z}$.